# How to implement elements comparsion in tensor by Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, loss-function

In my custom loss function, I want to implement this specific computation:

Input:

```
tensor A: placeholder([None, 1])
tensor B: placeholder([None, 1])
```

And A, B has the same shape.

Output:

```
tensor res: placeholder([None, 1]).
```

**For example:**

```
tensor   A: [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3,...]
tensor   B: [4, 9, 2, 3, 5, 9, 4,...]
tensor res: [4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4,...]
```

At first, res[0] = B[0], if A[i] == A[i-1], then res[i] = res[i-1]; else, res[i] = B[i]. So we get **res=[4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4,...]**.

I'm really troubled in the question, and I'm not expected in tensorflow.Hope to answer, thx.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that there is a direct way to deal with this in tensorflow. But, you can create your own operation or implement this in a crude way in tensorflow

1. `condition` - Create an array with 1s at index which pass the condition and 0s at the rest. (Can be easily parallelized and in tensorflow use `tf.while_loop`)
2. `prefixedSum` - Use [prefix sum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum) on `condition` to create this array. (No direct implementation, but [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/813) can help)
3. `reducedB` - use the `condition` to create an array of selected elements choosing index from `prefixedSum` array. (can be implemented using `tf.while_loop`)
4. `ans` - create the final array using the index from `prefixedSum` and looking up that index in `reducedB`. (Again can be implemented using `tf.while_loop`)